# Clear drawn graphics on a picturebox without clearing original picture

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+

In a geographical software written in C#, a `PictureBox` is used to show  GIS map that is saved as a `png` file in a temporary directory. There is some geometric shapes we need to be drawn on map. We used `System.Drawing` methods to perform this action.

Sometimes we need to change some properties these shapes or delete them, we need to remove the shapes without making beneath them black. Drawing them again with `Color.Transparent` obviously doesn't work, using `Graphics#Clear(Color.Transparent)` doesn't work too for the same reason.

We even tried using another picture box with transparent background that is used only for purpose of drawing shapes on; so that when we use `Graphics#Clear(Color.Transparent)` map container remains untouched. Sounded like a perfect idea at first, but because i don't know how and why it makes map container `PictureBox` invisible and map viewer panel is totally black, this idea failed too.

```
MapViewerForm
    |-- Toolbar
    |-- StatusBar
    |-- MapViewer Panel (Provides scrollbars)
            |-- MapContainer Pictutebox
            |-- Shapes drawing canvas PictureBbox (The same size and location as map container, only difference is z-order)
```

I prefer to use the two `PictureBox`es and making 'layers' idea, i think it's less unprofessional than the other idea (I am actually a java developer and this is a C# project!), I think there should be something like java's `JLayeredPane` in C# to adjust z-order of those two picture boxes and omit black screen bug, But if there is a solution to draw shapes on map container itself and then clear them without losing portions of maps lying behind them i'd appreciate that answer too.

P.S: If we load map picture from file and store it in a `Bitmap` or `Image` private field and when we need to clear drawings, load image from that field with a piece of code like `picMapArea.Image = MapViewer.getInstance().getMapImage();` (Note: `MapViewer` is a singleton class) the painted shapes will be gone but it's obviously not anything like a "good idea" because of poor performance and lagging.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whenever you have something what standard components doesn't supports - you have to create your own. Or search for one. Idea with standard components behaving in non-standard way is really bad. What you can do: subclass `PictureBox`, provide interface to handle background picture and all elements what are put on top of it (`MapElement` -> `MapElementOval`, etc), add interaction with the user (if necessary, it's unclear what you are actually trying to achieve, sounds like map with markers, maybe you want to be able to click and move those markers), draw everything in `OnPaint` as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply draw the shapes in an event handler for the picturebox Paint event.

To restore the view, all you have to do is call the picturebox `Invalidate()` method, so it repaints the Image, and not draw anything in your Paint event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an additional Bitmap:

```
Bitmap original = LoadBitmap(...);





Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(original);

Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(copy);

// draw some extra


PictureBox1.Image = copy;
```

Comment: It's similar to the "P.S" part but we don't make a copy first. We're trying it and i hope it works, thanks :)